# how to get the count of notes from a table order by day?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have a table named notes it contains 2 fields notes and posted date in time stamp format.

I want to display it in a graph format. For that, I would like to get the details as an array that contains date ( not in time stamp format; in date format ) as array index and no of notes as the value.

How to get it ? Please help me

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck at the moment, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select date(datetime_field) as dt,count(*) as number
from table
group by dt
```

if you mean unix_timestamp

```
select from_unixtime(unixtimestamp_field,'%Y-%m-%d') as dt,count(*) as number
from table
group by dt
```